# Are velocity fields in energy conserving systems necessarily irrotational?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, vector-fields, flow, vortex

Let's assume that we consider a bunch of particles (e.g. water or air) and we describe their velocity using a vector field $\vec v(\vec x, t)$.

Moreover, let's assume that there is no external potential and hence the total energy is just an integral over the kinetic energy:
$$ E = \int d^3 x \; \rho \frac{m}{2} \vec v^2    ,$$
where $\rho$ is the particle density. The total energy should be conserved, i.e. 
$$ \frac{\partial E }{\partial t} =0 \, . \tag{1}$$
*Is it possible to conclude from Eq. 1 that $\vec v$ is necessarily irrotational:*
$$ \nabla \times \vec v =0? $$

Comment: Consider a spinning bucket filled with water (no friction). $E$ is conserved but the velocity field has a curl that is twice the angular velocity of the bucket (for rigid motion of the fluid). So I would say no, unless you consider the walls of the bucket an "external potential". However, you can consider a bucket without walls: a ball of fluid in vacuum held together by gravity (in this case the gravity is not an "external potential" because it is auto-generated by the fluid. Same thing: the curl of the fluid is twice the angular velocity of your "planet".

Comment: Dimension of the right side of your energy equation doesn't match with the left side. I guess, the equation should be $\int d^3x{\rho \over 2} \mathbf v^2$

Comment: @Minotaur $\rho$ denotes the particle density not mass density.